# Is it proper notation to add a condition to set with English?

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

Say you have a sequence defined as $A=(X_n)_{n\in I}$, where $I$ is the index set. Possible subsequences of $A$ can be defined as:

$$B=(X_n)_{n\in J}, J\subseteq I$$

In other words, possible subsequences of $A$ are obtained by restricting the index set to a smaller subset.
Then, the set of all possible subsequences of $A$ can be denoted as:

$$ C=\{(X_n)_{n\in J} \mid J\subseteq I\} $$

If you wanted to add more where clauses for each possible sequence in set $C$ (and couldn't change the first definition of $C$) would it be improper to say that $D=C$ with $\operatorname{length}((X_n)_{n\in J})\geq4$?

Comment: Yes, you should rather use $D=\{(X_n)_{n\in J}\in C: {\rm length}((X_n)_n)\ge 4\}$.

Comment: Thanks very much. To add even more where statements to that, would you use commas after the first ":" to separate subsequent "where" statements?

Comment: Yes, commas, you can also insert (small) texts like 'and', 'for', 'otherwise', they might actually also increase readability.

Comment: Many thanks. One last question if you have time: in ={()∈∈:length(())≥4}, why is it (())≥4 and not (()∈) ≥4? Is it just redundant to refer to the index set J again?

Comment: I was just too lazy to type it all.. :)